# ReactJS _ Text Editor - Existing a text editor for ReactJS as complete as the libreoffice editor?

Tags: reactjs, text-editor

I'm trying to implement a blog app in my React App. I'm seeking for a very complete text editor allowing to handle very globally the properties of the text. I have though of DraftJS but seems it isn't allowing a very big set of settings parameters.

Existing a more complete ReactJS's text editor ?

Update:

- [React Draft Wysiwyg](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs) seems pretty good and easily customizable,

Any hints would be great,
Thanks

Comment: draftjs is pretty low level. you could implement anything you want with it. it just doesn't come premade with everything you want